# NFS mount command failed: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, nfs

I am working on an embedded board, running embedded Linux on it.
I want to mount the directory from my Linux Host machine (Ubuntu 20.04) to my embedded board.

As per the document shared with the board, I ran the following command to mount.

`# busybox mount -t nfs -o nolock -o tcp -o rsize=32768,wsize=32768 192.168.60.68:/home/paras/nfs_mount/ /nfsroot/`

Where,
192.168.60.68 is the IP of my Linux Host machine (Ubuntu 20.04).

When I ran this command on the **embedded board**, throws the error.

```
# busybox mount -t nfs -o nolock -o tcp -o rsize=32768,wsize=32768 192.168.60.68:/home/paras/nfs_mount/ /nfsroot/ 

mount: mounting 192.168.60.68:/home/paras/nfs_mount/ on /nfsroot/ failed: Permission denied
```

On my Linux system (Ubuntu 20.04) firewall is not active and nfs-server is ruunig.

```
paras@paras-desktop:~/$    systemctl status nfs-server
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2022-11-14 13:50:40 IST; 1min 38s ago
    Process: 14244 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 14245 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 14245 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 14 13:50:39 paras-desktop systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Nov 14 13:50:40 paras-desktop systemd[1]: Finished NFS server and services.

paras@paras-desktop:~/$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

paras@paras-desktop:~/$ ifconfig
wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.60.68  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.63.255
        inet6 fe80::155e:fa5a:a0b:cb37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:2b:f9:e7:0a:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 481975  bytes 483409798 (483.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 284309  bytes 91521351 (91.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Is your home directory actually exported for access via NFS, `exportfs -v`?

Comment: @user1686
Thanks for the replay.  I ran ``` exportfs -v ``` command on my Linux (Ubuntu) desktop. it shows nothing.

```
paras@paras-desktop:~$  sudo exportfs -v
paras@paras-desktop:~$  
```



Do you have any idea how I export it?

Comment: To NFS mount remote directories, you need to run `rpcbind`, `rpc.idmapd`, `rpc.statd` & `rpc.mountd` on the server. See the man pages for these as well as for `exportfs` on how to configure them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only NFS-mount paths that are specifically *exported* (similar to creating a "share" on Windows), which is done through the `/etc/exports` file.

For example, to export `/home/paras/nfs` for clients from your LAN, use:

```
/home/paras/nfs 192.168.60.0/24(sec=sys,rw,no_subtree_check)
```

or:

```
/home/paras/nfs -rw,no_subtree_check 192.168.60.0/24(sec=sys) 192.168.70.0/24(sec=sys)
```

After making the edits, run `exportfs -rv` to apply the changes.

Beware that NFS has *no* client authentication by default – all it checks is the IP address, so avoid exporting filesystems to `*` unless you must. (NFS supports Kerberos via sec=krb5, but I doubt it would work with embedded Linux anyway.)

For a related reason, the NFS server will not allow clients to have root privileges – whenever an NFS client claims that access is performed by root (UID 0), it actually gets the privileges of the `nobody` user instead. (This can be disabled using "no_root_squash", but it's better to just grant the necessary minimum access to the "nobody" user instead.)

If the embedded client uses UIDs that don't really makes sense on your server system, you might want to remap *all* access to a specific UID using the `all_squash` and `anonuid=` export options.

Comment: After modifying exports file, I am able to mount the Linux Desktop folder to my embedded Linux board.  But the mounted folder (nfs) is read-only for embedded Linux board.  From my embedded Linux board I am not able to create/modify the file.

Comment: Read-only how? Does it literally say "Read-only filesystem", or does it say "Permission denied"?

Comment: Run the "touch test.txt" command from my embedded Linux board. I got error,  "touch: test.txt: Permission denied"

Comment: What UID is the command being run as? Does that UID have write permissions to the directory?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
the root cause was the missing permission on the sharing machine. a

```
chmod 777 .
```

on this point fixed my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).